# Java: wicket unable to find component

Tags: java, wicket, war

Trying to re-package something maintained by another developer and running into a wicket component issue.  Honestly just looking for a point in the right direction to narrow down what is actually happening here.  I do not have access to the source-code only compiled war which I have decompiled.  This seemingly when run in their perfect environment runs properly, but I need to run a slightly different version of java.

Seems from this error that it just cant find the "feature" component. how can i back-trace this?  decompiling the class for the ServerStatusPage I only see "features" as a variable.  Is there even a quick way I can remove the offending area of the status page for now and repackage the war file?  When i tried i ended up getting into more issues saying the i was excluding a components that should be there.

the full error during runtime is as follows:

```
2018-02-28 23:04:02,603 ERROR [wicket.RequestCycle] (default task-23) Unable to find component with id 'feature' in [MarkupContainer [Component id = 0, page = extensis.esp.webadmin.pages.serverstatus.ServerStatusPage, path = 7:features:0.ListItem, isVisible = true, isVersioned = true]]. This means that you declared wicket:id=feature in your markup, but that you either did not add the component to your page at all, or that the hierarchy does not match.
[markup = vfs:/content/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/extensis/esp/webadmin/pages/serverstatus/ServerStatusPage.html, index = 34, current = '<span wicket:id="feature">' (line 52, column 6)]: wicket.markup.MarkupException: Unable to find component with id 'feature' in [MarkupContainer [Component id = 0, page = extensis.esp.webadmin.pages.serverstatus.ServerStatusPage, path = 7:features:0.ListItem, isVisible = true, isVersioned = true]]. This means that you declared wicket:id=feature in your markup, but that you either did not add the component to your page at all, or that the hierarchy does not match.
[markup = vfs:/content/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/extensis/esp/webadmin/pages/serverstatus/ServerStatusPage.html, index = 34, current = '<span wicket:id="feature">' (line 52, column 6)]
    at wicket.markup.MarkupStream.throwMarkupException(MarkupStream.java:290) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1381) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:982) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:917) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:1712) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:927) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.Component.render(Component.java:1526) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.renderItem(ListView.java:680) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.onRender(ListView.java:641) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.Component.render(Component.java:1526) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1334) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:982) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:917) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:1712) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:927) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.Component.render(Component.java:1526) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1334) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:944) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:864) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.Component.render(Component.java:1526) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:413) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.respond(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:226) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.request.compound.DefaultResponseStrategy.respond(DefaultResponseStrategy.java:49) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.request.compound.AbstractCompoundRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractCompoundRequestCycleProcessor.java:66) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.RequestCycle.doProcessEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:902) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:929) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1010) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1084) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:454) [wicket.jar:]
    at wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:219) [wicket.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174) [undertow-servlet-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793) [undertow-core-1.3.15.Final.jar:1.3.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_141]
```

The html file being processed is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="NO-CACHE">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <script language="JavaScript"><!--
        function setIFrameContents(frameName, contents) {
             var iFrame = window.frames[frameName]; 
             iFrame.document.open();     
             iFrame.document.write(contents); 
             iFrame.document.close();
        }
    //--></script>


    <title wicket:id="pagetitle">Status</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="main">

        <div class="header"></div>

        <div class="nav-and-content">

            <div class="navbar">
                <span wicket:id="navBar"></span>                                                    
            </div> <!--end nav bar div-->

            <div class="lockButton">
                <form wicket:id="lockUnlockForm">
                    <input wicket:id="lockButton" type="image" src=""/>
                    <input wicket:id="unlockButton" type="image" src=""/>                   
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    <span class="title" wicket:id="title">Status</span>
                    <span class="error" wicket:id="feedback">Error verbiage if any goes here.</span>                    
                </p>

                <br/>

                <span wicket:id="features">
                    <span wicket:id="feature"></span>
                </span>

            </div> <!-- end content -->

        <div class="clear"></div>           

        </div> <!-- end nav-and-content -->



        <div class="footer"></div>

        <div class="langs" wicket:id="localeSelectPanel"></div>

    </div> <!--end main div-->

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks and pardon my ignorance on some of this.

Answer (score 1):

Code using ListView should look like the following:

```
ListView lv = new ListView("features", listOfFeatures) {
   @Override protected void onPopulate(ListItem<Feature> li) {
       li.add(new FeaturePanel("feature", li.getModel()));
   }

}
```

In your exception message component `0` is the ListItem. It seems for some reason line `li.add(new FeaturePanel("feature"));` is not executed, so `0` has no child with id `feature`.

Since you do not have the source code attaching the debugger won't help much but at least you will be able to see what is in the component tree. Just put a breakpoint at MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1381) and check what is the value of `children` member field when `this` is a ListItem with id=`0`.

From the class names I can say that this is Wicket 1.3 or earlier, and this is very old version of Wicket!

Comment: thanks for this! i will try and report back :) also hoping that the next version includes some updated versions :/